# Hystrix and Spring @Async in combination

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

I'm using Hystrix library for the Spring Boot project (`spring-cloud-starter-hystrix`). I have a `@Service` class annotated with `@HystrixCommand` and it works as expected.

But, when I add the method annotated with `@Async` in that same service class then the Hystrix doesn't work, and fallback method is never called. What could cause this problem and how to fix it?

This is the `Application` class:

```
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        
    }
}
```

This is the service class:

```
@Service
public class TemplateService {

    @HystrixCommand(
            fallbackMethod = "getGreetingFallback",
            commandProperties = {@HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "1500")}
    )
    public String getGreeting() {
        URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8090/greeting");

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
        if (response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
            return response.getBody();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getGreetingFallback(Throwable e) {
        return null;
    }

    @Async
    public void async(String message) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.info(MessageFormat.format("Received async message {0}", message));
    }
}
```

`@EnableAsync` annotation is placed in a different class annotated with `@Configuration`, where I set some other Thread Executor options from properties file.

Comment: show us the relevant code & configuration along with error (*if any*)

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the code for `TemplateService` (*which doesn't implement interface*) and assuming the defaults on [`@EnableAsync`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html#proxyTargetClass--) it is safe to concur that CGLIB proxies are created by spring.

Thus the `@HystrixCommand` annotation on `getGreeting()` *isn't* inherited by the service proxy class; which explains the reported behavior.

To get past this error keep the `@HystrixCommand` and `@Async` method separated in different service because enabling JDK proxies will also not help and I am not sure about AspectJ mode.

Refer [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying) for further information on Spring proxy mechanism.

Comment: Thank you. So the same method then cant use the Hystrix library and execute asynchronously?

Comment: Yes .. same method can't be used for both

Comment: The separation is a bad idea because you'll have double the number of threads - one for `@ASync` and one for `@HysterixCommand`

Comment: @mjaggard what is the alternative you would suggest here ?

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond Use Hystrix the way it is documented - not with the Spring annotations. https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix

Comment: @mjaggard Today we have Spring in almost all enterprise applications, so its likely that both will overlap somewhere or other. Even the hysterix is supported by Spring via its starter so I see no reason why they should not be used together. Moreover in documentation I see no reference not to mix them (may be I missed something here) Also OP mentioned that only the `@Async` part doesn't work for which a working solution is provided. The separation part is essential given the way spring works (your insight here is valued, but lacks a supportive argument so do shed more light on your thoughts)

Comment: It's not that there's some definitive reason not to mix them, but both will start new threads to perform the operation so if you use them together you'll use one thread for the Async and one thread for the HystrixCommand - which is unnecessary. Both implementations have to maintain a thread pool which must be correctly sized and in addition, you have the overhead of handing over between threads (copying CPU cache, etc.) This explains why more threads is bad https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/sample_chapter/article.php/c13533/Why-Too-Many-Threads-Hurts-Performance-and-What-to-do-About-It.htm

Comment: @mjaggard Agreed about the thread overhead and all, but the base question remains - For the scenario which OP has encountered what would be the alternative solution (apart from segregation of the methods in two services mentioned in answer) ...